# Does a module for real-time data plotting exist?

Tags: views, charts

There are several Drupal modules that allow to plot /chart data stored in database tables. Is there any module that can chart or plot data in real-time? For a specific example, I have a mobile application that is reading sensor data (say from an accelerometer) and sends that to the Drupal server. I want to plot the data as and when updated in real-time or near real-time. Does any specific module that can do this exist?

Answer (score 3):

[Google Chart Tools](https://drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools)

> Display live data on your site using Google Chart Tools Google Chart
>   Tools module provides a simple API to Build custom interactive SVG
>   charts.
>
> **Views integration**
>
> The Google Chart Tools Views module is based on the Views built in
>   aggregation function. For basic instructions of using the Views
>   integration module check the README.txt file

**or**

[Quant](https://drupal.org/project/quant) provides an engine for producing quantitative, time-based analytics for virtually any Drupal component. Quant takes raw data about normal Drupal actions, such as node creation, and plots the activity over time, with the selected time being configurable. See the screenshot provided for a better understanding.

> Quant API (**easily provide your own charts**)
>
> The real power of Quant lies in it's ability to generate these charts
>   with very little provided information. Quant offers a simple, yet
>   flexible API to allow developers to include quant charts with their
>   modules.

[image]